# Convert .a file into .lib file for C/C++ project

Tags: c++, c, dll, .a, .lib

I have got a question. In my quest to add external packages to my C/C++ project, i read differents topics about how to convert static library (.a) into static library (.lib). I downloaded packages and i wanted to add them manually using their pathway.

I added my packages as followed:

1 / Add the path of the headers in the compiler directories for the project:

-> Project / Properties menu

-> On the left tree, choose Configuration properties - C / C ++ - General

-> On the right table, the first line "Other Include directories": add the directory (s) of your library containing the headers

2 / Add the path of the .lib in the compiler directories for the project:

-> Project / Properties menu

-> On the left tree, choose Configuration Properties - Link Editor - General

-> On the right table, the line "Directory of additional libraries": add the directory (s) of your library containing the .libs

3 / Specify the libraries with which your project is linked:

-> Project / Properties menu

-> On the left tree, choose Configuration Properties - Link Editor - Enter

-> On the right table, the first line "Additional dependencies": add the .lib library (s) with which your project must be linked

But I looked for .lib files to add to my linker input instead, I found .a files and .dll files and I didn't know what to do. . a files and .lib files are almost identical. It seems like .a files are used under linux while .lib are used under windows. I tried to add the .a files unsuccesfilly. I wondered if I could convert an .a file into a .lib file.
Can i convert a static library (.a) into a static library (.lib).

Thanks

Comment: Since you're referencing steps for a specific IDE, it would be good to also state which IDE it is as that could be important. Also any details about the platform you're using - I presume Windows but it's not clear. Also, why do you need to convert `.a` to `.lib`? Do you not have access to a `.lib` or the source code for it?

Comment: I work with visual studio 2019 on Windows 10. I don't have access to neither .lib or source code.  Only file type available ar .a or .dll.

Comment: Library files with extension `.a` are typically generated by GCC or Clang. They are *not* compatible with `.lib` files from MSVC. Both are basically archives of object files (`.o` or `.obj`), but the ABI is different between compilers, especially in C++. So it is impossible.

Comment: If i remember the ABI defines how arguments are passed, how virtual function tables are represented, how exceptions are thrown, the size of basic data types, and quite a number of other things... Do i have any others options ? i guess no ...

Comment: @ManuLAB There is no universal C++ ABI. Besides, any code in a library likely depends on a certain C/C++ runtime which is compiler and even version specific.

Comment: If you have a Windows .dll, you can use `dumpbin` and `lib` to create .lib and .exp files.